My ECS task mapped with portMapping = 9200 but the application end point is running only in port 8080
I am fairly new to AWS and docker.
What I have done is --

I have created a sample spring-boot get endpoint
Created a docker image from it and pushed the same to DockerHub
Created an ECS cluster and defined the task for the same, selected Fargate.
My cluster and task definition both are running.

While creating the task,
I configured the portMapping to be 9200 
but when I hit the public IP url with http://[ip]:9200/(endpoint), this gives
"The site can't be reached" 
But when I hit the url with 8080 port http://[ip]:8080/(endpoint), I get proper response.
My question is what is the reason for the same --
when I have configured the portMapping to be 9200, I would expect the url with port 9200 should work.
One possible reason could be my Dockerfile where I have mentioned EXPOSE 8080. Is it because of this, that this is only working on port 8080? I need some help and advise please.

The Dockerfile EXPOSE line doesn't do a whole lot.  What port is your Spring Boot application listening on?  If you want to use a non-default port, you need to change your application configuration to match; this isn't something Docker or ECS can transparently do.  (It's more common to just use the application's default port and remap it externally.)

Your SpringBoot app is listening on port 8080. All the other things like the Dockerfile EXPOSE and the ECS port mappings, need to match the port your application is actually listening on. You can't pick a random port somewhere else, it has to be the same as the port the application is actually using.

@DavidMaze I haven't changed the application port so its by default running in port 8080. So, do you mean to say, if application default port is 8080, whatever I provide in ECS cluster portMapping (say 9200 or 9000) it won't be of any use until I change it in application's properties file?

@MarkB - ok I get the point, the port in the application's properties file is the one that needs to be mapped everywhere in EXPOSE or portMapping. If this does not match, it will pick up the one from application level itself. Is my understanding correct?

It doesn't "pick up one from application itself". The application is simply listening on that port. When you go to the IP address for the Fargate task you are really just going directly to the container and are able to get to the port directly, which is why that worked. If you were doing EC2 deployments that would not have worked without the correct port mapping. And if you add a load balancer in front of your app, the load balancer would definitely not work at all unless you got the port mappings correct. Also EXPOSE isn't even looked at by ECS.
